# how to force a Ubuntu to just connect a special IP

Tags: security

I want to install an Ubuntu on a USB drive and configure it to use in programming contest.

so I want to force Ubuntu to connect just to a special site not whole web. how to do it?

Comment: I think you should clarify a little bit what you want to achieve, and why. Is it the web browser you want to restrict, or everything? Why do you want it? This is relevant, as different means may give differing results.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `iptables`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j REJECT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j REJECT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 15.15.15.15 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -s 15.15.15.15 -j ACCEPT
```

change 15.15.15.15 to your website's server ip.

Test it, I've not tested it.

A full tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands).

> Note: This will break system/security updates.

Comment: Note that doing this will break system/security updates.

Comment: @dopey I edited.